# Lines from text file aren't assigning into two dimensional array properly

Tags: c++

[image: Debug screenshot]

I am creating two dimensional array of chars to write text from file line by line
As i read the file lines into the buffer it reads properly and i can see output in the console.
But despite the fact i am writing every line from file to info array, when i watch value of info[0] info[2] info[3]... etc i get the last line of file written in every of those.

Can someone, please, point me at a problem?

P.S. I know there is a better way to work with files in C++, but i am limited to fgets, fputs, fputc and other basic functions , as a part of programming course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a strcpy() from buffer to info[c] in your loop instead of the assignment you are currently doing.

Comment: Wow, missed that, i am dumb as hell :c
Many thanks for your help!